# How to convert Laravel collection array to json

Tags: json, laravel-5, laravel-collection

How can i convert this Laravel collection array to json format like below.

```
//All records from users table.
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

// Required json format.
return '{
          "data": [

            {
              "DT_RowId": "row_1",
              "id": "Tiger",
              "clear": "Nixon",
              "fsssf": "System Architect",
              "tex": "t.nixon@datatables.net",
              "created_at": "Edinburgh",
              "updated_at": "Edinburgh"
            },
             {
              "DT_RowId": "row_2",
              "id": "Tiger",
              "clear": "Nixon",
              "fsssf": "System Architect",
              "tex": "t.nixon@datatables.net",
              "created_at": "Edinburgh",
              "updated_at": "Edinburgh"
            }

          ],
  "options": [],
  "files": []
}';
```

Sorry for the basic question,but i am unable to convert this into this jso.

Comment: $users is a collection and he has a method "->toJson()".

Comment: In Laravel 9 you can still use the `@json` directive. Also you can find this in the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-json

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses).

You can use toJson(),to convert the collection to json object.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get()->toJson();
dd($users);
```

You can also can do this in simple php way by using json_encode function

```
$users = json_encode($users);
```

Have a look at this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Greetings and happy coding!

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking into doing if for a blade template you can use the `@json` [Blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data), like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PARAMS = @json($params)
</script>
```

*P.S.Tested in Laravel 5.6*

Answer (score 5):

> add "use Response;"

```
return Response::json([
    'data' => $value
], 200);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: this has to be the most useful, just add the response libraries and good to go

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things you can do, you can use default method ->toJson() with the user collection like this

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$users->toJson();
```

If you do have troubles with it them you can php build in json_encode method here is the full documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
json_encode($users)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

if we you laravel 5.5 then you should use  [eloquent-resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel you can easily serialize your php object like so :

```
public static function getLocataireByCin($cin)
    {
        return Locataire::where('cin', $cin)
            ->first()
            ->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

and then retrieve it on your frontEnd (using js/jquery for example ) :

```
$("#cinLocataire").keyup(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('Caisse.store') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                cin: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function (locataireData) {
                var locataire = JSON.parse(locataireData); // <-- here
                console.log(
                    locataire.nom
                );
            },
        })
    });
```